# How to select by id in array of elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I'm struggling a bit with how to do a simple selection of a specific element in a element array in JavaScript. Consider the following:

```
var htmlString = "<span>someText</span><input type='hidden' class='idBox' name='id' data-id='6026' value='6026'>";
var eleArray = $.parseHTML(htmlString);                    
var inputVal = $(eleArray[1]).val();
```

`inputVal` will hold the value of the input field. In this specific case it would be hold 6026.. However I don't like the way I get this value by selecting index 1 in the `eleArray`, which is the input element. I would like to select it by the input elements id, which in this case by class would be `idBox` or name `id`.. But I don't know how to do that.

Any advice ?

Comment: Put the elements in the array to a document fragment.

Comment: did you try `document.getElementById()` to retrieve your element based on its id?

Comment: @Pochwar the elements are not in `document` - they won't be found when searching the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parseHTML` will give you an array of elements which you can use with jQuery, so you can `filter` in the usual way you would with elements added to the DOM:

```js
var htmlString = "<span>someText</span><input type='hidden' class='idBox' name='id' data-id='6026' value='6026'>";
var eleArray = $.parseHTML(htmlString);                    
var inputVal = $(eleArray).filter("[name='id']").val()
console.log(inputVal);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) syntax :

```js
const htmlString = "<span>someText</span><input type='hidden' class='idBox' name='id' data-id='6026' value='6026'>";
$($.parseHTML(htmlString)).filter(".idBox").val();
// => '6026'
```

Other solution using the input name :

```js
const htmlString = "<span>someText</span><input type='hidden' class='idBox' name='id' data-id='6026' value='6026'>";
$($.parseHTML(htmlString)).filter("input[name='id']").val();
```